# Can not generate a CMake command

Tags: cmake

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(main)

SET(MAIN main)
SET(MAIN_OUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/out.txt")
add_executable(${MAIN} main.cpp)

# command is unknown
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${MAIN_OUT}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ./${MAIN} > ${MAIN_OUT}
    DEPENDS ${MAIN}
)
```

After compiling, I just want to be able to type

```
make out.txt
```

However, cmake seems to be unaware of this target ("no rule"). In the build directory, a call of

```
grep out.txt -r *
```

finds no files containing out.txt. How can I make my target callable? I know this has probably asked before, but I have not found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to type "make out.txt", you probably want [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) instead of `add_custom_command`.  This creates a target which can be built, and in building executes the specified commands.

Rather than call this target "out.txt" which would misleadingly make it look like a text file instead of a target, I'd recommend something more like "RunMain" or "GetOutputOfMain".

If you can specify a recent version of CMake as the minimum, you can use "generator expressions" within the command part of your `add_custom_target` call.  This isn't documented for `add_custom_target`, but you can read about generator expressions in the docs for [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command).  I'm not sure what the minimum required version of CMake should be set to in order to have generator expressions available.

So, your CMakeLists.txt could be changed to something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
project(Test)

add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)

set(MainOut "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/out.txt")
add_custom_target(RunMain $<TARGET_FILE:MyExe> > ${MainOut}
                  COMMENT "Running MyExe with output redirected to ${MainOut}")

# Ensure MyExe is built before trying to build the custom target
add_dependencies(RunMain MyExe)
```

Then just do `make RunMain` to generate out.txt.

If you don't want to specify such a high minimum version, you can use the obsolete [`LOCATION`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aLOCATION) target property instead:

```
get_target_property(MyExeLocation MyExe LOCATION)
add_custom_target(
    RunMain ${MyExeLocation} > ${MainOut}
    COMMENT "Running ${MyExeLocation} with output redirected to ${MainOut}")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Just for interest: What would I need to do if I want RunMain only to be executed once after the binary has built? (Assuming that the binary always produces the same output after compilation)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  RunMain has to be executed (i.e. built) only when you want to build it.  It's not part of the `ALL` target, so it won't ever be built automatically.  If you're wanting things automated, you can use your original approach of `add_custom_command` to apply the command as a post-build event.  That way you don't have a separate target; you can't "make" it - you just build MyExe and the command runs on completion of the build.  The command would be something like `add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe POST_BUILD COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:MyExe> > ${MainOut} COMMENT "...")`.

Comment: Agreed, we do not need a separate target in this case. But if I really want a separate one, would that be possible?

Comment: Well, my answer shows how to put in the custom target, and there's nothing to stop you having the post-build command too.  You *could* look at trying to have a post-build command execute building the custom target.  However, if the custom target depends on the thing being built (MyExe in this case), there will be an interesting recursion where the post-build of MyExe triggers building MyExe!  You'd need to get round that some way, but it all seems pretty hacky.  I'd plunk for either the custom target and manually run it whenever required, or (preferably) the post-build command - but not both.